# Hibernate Soft Delete with Spring JPA Audit

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring JPA in my project, and using auditing fields to keep track of the events of an entity.
I have an abstract class named Auditable, which has all the fields I need:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
abstract class Auditable {
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false) lateinit var createdBy: String

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false) lateinit var creationDatetime: Instant

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column lateinit var lastModifiedBy: String

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column lateinit var lastModifiedDatetime: Instant
}
```

I need to apply a soft delete for some entities. Using `@SQLDelete` is pretty simple and straight-forward, but it does not allow integrating the user that modified ("deleted") the entry. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "example", schema = "public")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE example SET deletion_datetime = NOW(), last_modified_datetime = NOW() WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deletion_datetime IS NULL")
internal data class Example(
    @Id @Column val id: UUID,
    @Column val name: String,
    @Column val description: String
) : Auditable()
```

`deletion_datetime` (which could be any other flag for logical delete) is only created via migration, directly into the table. It is not mapped by the entity.

As far as I understood, there is no integration between Hibernate and SpEL, so I could not simply add to the `@SQLDelete` something like `SET lastModifiedBy = ?#{principal.getOrElse(null)}`.

I tried to add an implementation of `@PreRemove`, trying to get the implementation of `AuditorAware` (where I extract the e-mail from an id token), but it does not work.

How can I achieve the soft delete, setting the user who performed the action?